# Different behaviour of axis2 using jre for linux/windows

Tags: java, jetty, apache-axis, axiom

I have an app (jar) that starts an embedded jetty server 8.1.18.v20150929. This server, deploys an webapp(war) which executes an axis2 client.

When I run it in Windows, the app works OK. But in Linux does not.

The jar app starts with this command:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

and uses jre 7u79.

This is the error in linux when tries to invoke the service :

```
Duplicate declaration for namespace prefix 'soapenv'
```

I checked the soap envelope and I found a difference:

WINDOWS:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">...
```

LINUX:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
  xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">...
```

Why the soapenv is duplicated in linux? The only difference is the jre version (linux/windows).

Another thing, classpath cointains these jars that have some classes with the same name and path:

- axiom-dom-1.2.19.jar
- axiom-impl-1.2.19.jar

for some reason, windows uses axiom-impl-1.2.19.jar for generate the envelope and linux uses axiom-dom-1.2.19.jar. The class used is org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.common.SOAPFactoryImpl and is present in both jars

Thanks!

Comment: Both Java 7 and Jetty 8 are EOL (End of Life), consider upgrading.

Comment: Thanks, I Cannot upgrade for restrictions of my Company

Comment: Neither axiom-dom-1.2.19.jar nor axiom-impl-1.2.19.jar contain org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory.

Comment: Sorry, the class is an implementation of SOAPFactory: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.common.SOAPFactoryImpl